# Class name conflict between Rails app and Rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have a `Document` model in my Rails 4 app which starts like this:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  TYPES = [FileList, Article, VariantList, LinkedItemsList].collect(&:model_name)
  ...
end
```

The `TYPES` array contains a list of other models in my app and is used in a few places, for example to display a list of possible document types in one of my forms.

Now I'm writing a Rake task to automate some stuff and I get this error at line 2 in my Document model when I run the task:

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'model_name' for Rake::FileList:Class`

So apparently there's the `Rake::FileList` class which is being loaded first and I get a name conflict. Using `::FileList` in my code doesn't help, I get the same error.

Any idea how to get around this without renaming my model?

**UPDATE:**

My Rake task definition looks like this:

```
namespace :store do
  desc 'Some description'
  task :my_task_name, [:a_parameter_name] => [:environment] do |t, args|
    ...
  end
end
```

I think this is loading the environment correctly, as I'm calling (loading from DB) some other models before I get to `Document` and that is working correctly.

Comment: In your rake task are you loading the environment? like `task mytask: :environment do`

Comment: @JCorcuera I updated my question with my task definition

Answer (score 0):

One think you can try is to give it an alias to `FileList`, at the end of you class definition:

```
class FileList < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

FileListCopy = FileList
```

then in your rake access to `FileListCopy`.

Comment: tried this, I named the alias DocumentFileList and change it in my `TYPE` array, but I'm getting `NameError: uninitialized constant DocumentFileList` now

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling FileList from Document model, it tries to resolve this constant in the following order:

1. It tries to find the constant in the elements of the [Module.nesting](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Module.html#method-c-nesting) chain. In your case nesting is just `[Document]` and it does not contain `FileList` constant.
2. Then it tries to find constant in object's ancestors.
3. And finally the constant is looked up in `Object`.

Rake exposes its DSL globally by extending `Object` with [Rake::DSL](https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/master/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb) module. Thus, while using rake you're always getting `FileList` from the rake.

To overcome this issue you may move all your code into namespace. For example `MyApp::FileList` and `MyApp::Document`. In that case constant lookup algorithm will try to find constant in the elements of the nesting (`[MyApp::Document, MyApp]`). The second element of the nesting (`MyApp`) contain `FileList` constant. So, it would be resolved from `MyApp` module instead of `Rake`.

To avoid such kind of issues it's always a good idea to put your code into some namespace.

Comment: Thanks for a thorough explanation. I realise I can put my model into a namespace, but that's not what you usually do with Rails models, unless they're in an engine. I leave it as a last resort, as I don't want to introduce a namespace just for this case.